# keytool keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jks, p7b

Attempting to add a certificate to the keystore so I can use it in an java based application. This is a new concept to me.

I have a .p7b certificate for the site and I put together a keytool command. When I enter it, I am prompted to specify a pwd and then I am prompted with the following error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Can anyone provide insight?

```
C:\Users\Desktop\>keytool -import -trustcacerts -file "service.site.com - SSL Cert.p7b" -keystore service.site.com.jks
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Comment: Where did you get this certificate from?

Answer (score 2):

You could try converting the key to CER (X509) and then try importing it:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer
```

I have encountered a similar problem even though I was trying to import a .pem file. The file contained only the a single certificate in both humain readable form and encapsulated within —–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—– and —–END CERTIFICATE—–. In java 7 (patch 71) the keytool failed to parse such file and threw the same error you've got. Once I removed the text portion of the file:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 11864724255945479761 (0xa4a7f7d949c31d11)
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=COM, ST=CA, O=Company, OU=ORG, CN=ORG/emailAddress=admin@company.org
    Validity
        Not Before: Jan  5 15:30:35 2015 GMT
        Not After : Jan  2 15:30:35 2025 GMT
```

it worked alright for me.

Please also take a look at the following article (https://myonlineusb.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-der-p7bpkcs7-pfxpkcs12-certificates/) as it explains the differences between various formats and provides commands how to convert from one format to another

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when importing a certificate using keytool. Starting with Java 6 release,an enhancement was added to keytool: namely that keytool can merge and import keystores that are in [PKCS12 format](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/installing-trusted-certificates-into-a-java-keystore). I concur with tazarov answer, you need to convert the PKCS#7 or P7B format (which basically is stored in Base64 ASCII format and has a file extension of .p7b or .p7c).

Before jumping in the solution I think is worth it to clarify some concepts. I will quote the below concepts from an excellent book:Bulletproof SSL and TLS by Ivan Ristić Copyright © 2015 Feisty Duck Limited. All rights reserved.

> PKCS#7 certificate(s) A complex format designed for the transport of signed or encrypted data, defined in RFC 2315. It’s usually seen with
>   .p7b and .p7c extensions and can include the entire certificate chain
>   as needed. This format is supported by Java’s keytool utility.
>
> Binary (DER) certificate Contains an X.509 certificate in its raw
>   form, using DER ASN.1 encoding.
>
> ASCII (PEM) certificate(s) Contains a base64-encoded DER certificate,
>   with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- used as the header and -----END
>   CERTIFICATE----- as the footer. Usually seen with only one certificate
>   per file, although some programs allow more than one certificate
>   depending on the context. For example, the Apache web server requires
>   the server certificate to be alone in one file, with all intermediate
>   certificates together in another.

SOLUTION

Fetch and Convert:

```
 openssl s_client -showcerts -connect "service.site.com - SSL Cert.p7b":443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```

Hope it helps!